# How can I generate an exponential Q-Q plot in R?

Tags: r, statistics

how can I generate an exponential Q-Q plot in R? For a normal Q-Q plot I use

```
qqnorm(sample)
```

Comment: Generate the exponential distribution and use `qqplot` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Hi Carl, is there an equivalent function for a Gumbel distribution instead of an exponential distribution? Say if I want to use QQplot to check if data fits Gumbel distribution instead of exponential? Many thanks.

Comment: @CountDOOKU  you should always start by searching CRAN.  There is a package `gumbel` which probably will meet your needs (I have not investigated it)

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT** (To reflect @Dason's input).

Like this:

[image]

```
set.seed(1)          # for reproducibility 
Z <- rexp(1000)      # random sample from exponential distribution
p <- ppoints(100)    # 100 equally spaced points on (0,1), excluding endpoints
q <- quantile(Z,p=p) # percentiles of the sample distribution
plot(qexp(p) ,q, main="Exponential Q-Q Plot",
     xlab="Theoretical Quantiles",ylab="Sample Quantiles")
qqline(q, distribution=qexp,col="blue", lty=2)
```

Comment: ppoints is useful here.  Any reason you chose only to use 100 points and estimate the sample quantiles from the data instead of just using the data directly?

Comment: @Dason - See edits. So `ppoints(n)` generates `n` equally spaced points *excluding the endpoints (0,1)*, which is better. I don't understand your reference to "using the data directly". Why don't you post an answer that does that.

Comment: Instead of using quantile to get 100 of the quantiles - why not just use ALL of the data as is common in a qqplot?  For an example take a look at the last example in `?qqplot`

Comment: Yeah, like I said in first comment :-).

Comment: Using the sample of points, leads to an incorrect estimate of the rate of the exponential distribution.

Comment: Hi Jlhoward, is there an equivalent function for a Gumbel distribution instead of an exponential distribution? Say if I want to use QQplot to check if data fits Gumbel distribution instead of exponential? Many thanks.

Comment: @countdooku There are functions for the gumbel distribution in the `dgumbel` package and also the `evd` package. Have you tried those?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `ggplot2` solution.

```
Z <- rexp(1000, rate = 2)
library(MASS)
params <- as.list(fitdistr(Z, "exponential")$estimate)

library(ggplot2)
qplot(sample = Z, geom = 'blank') +
  stat_qq(distribution = qexp, dparams = params)
```

Answer (score 4):

R has the `qqplot` function. jlhoward does it "manual" and calculates quantile of the data with `quantile` function. But in R you dont need to do it.

```
set.seed(1)
data = rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=2)
qqplot(x=qexp(ppoints(100)), y=data, main="Exponential Q-Q Plot",
       xlab="Theoretical Quantiles", ylab= "Your Data Quantiles")
qqline(data, distribution=qexp)
```

[click here to see R Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbrvY.png) (I dont have 10 reputation to post images)

I dont see the reason, why jlhoward only takes 100 points but not 1000 like the length of the data in his example. Or maybe it's just a typing error?

Comment: Hi z4, is there an equivalent function for a Gumbel distribution instead of an exponential distribution? Say if I want to use QQplot to check if data fits Gumbel distribution instead of exponential? Many thanks.